# texmate and django, is there intellisense?

Tags: python, macos, textmate

New to mac and textmate AND python.

I don't seem to be getting any intellisensewith textmate, is there a plugin?

what are the keyboard shortcuts I should know about (basic ones at this point).

thanks!

Comment: For those who don't know what he's talking about, IntelliSense is Microsoft's name for autocompletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [bundles](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/TextMate) for Django that make it easier to work with Django projects in TextMate. They offer the ability to search online for documentation, and there are a lot of "snippets" defined so you can type a few characters, hit Tab, and "auto"-complete some frequently-used strings, but none offer anything on the scope of IntelliSense.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of TextMate bundles that will satisfy you:

- [PySmell](http://code.google.com/p/pysmell/) -- Gives you VS-like dropdown of available methods.
- [Tempy](http://mtod.org/tempy/) -- ToolTips only. Not well built but extremely useful.